# ExtJS: Use of event listener in combobox to update fieldLabel in another form control

Tags: javascript, extjs, handler

I have a combo box in an ExtJS (5.1.2) grid panel that is a component in a dockedItems toolbar, defined as:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    flex: 1,
    width: 400,
    itemId: 'labCode',
    queryMode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    forceSelection: true,
    loading: true,
    fieldLabel: 'Select lab type',
    displayField: 'description',
    fieldName: 'description',
    valueField: 'code',
    store: 'Labs',
    listeners: {
        change: function(combo, value) {
            if (value) {
                record = this.getSelectedRecord();
                console.log(record.raw.units);
                units = record.raw.units;
                console.log(combo.up('grid').down('#labValue'))
                combo.up('grid').down('#labValue').fieldLabel = units
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the fieldLabel in another form component `#labValue` when I select an item from my dropdown. When I write the form component object to the console it is definitely giving the expected value, but on the form itself, the fieldLabel for the component `#labValue` is empty. How can I update the component `#labValue` with the new fieldLabel?

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to implement use of bindings as per the comment below, but am unsure of how to get the container widget given in the given fiddle into my dockedItems toolbar that is above my grid panel?

Comment: Is this Extjs 4? 5? 6?

Comment: Fixed. See above edit.

Comment: You'll might want to consider binding instead..

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean? All the answers I found use setText on the getCmp() method, which to me seems wrong.

Comment: For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/169m

Comment: Cool, I did not know you could do that.

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) please?

Comment: Use the `setFieldLabel` method on the field.

Comment: I just needed to make my form a `viewModel: {}` and it worked. While, the `setFieldLabel` method does work, I prefer the binding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

see fiddle in comment to your question. Should give you the answer.

Comment: I would accept the fiddle answer in the comment if I could, but I can't so I will just say it was the answer.